# Jquery Shopping Cart with add and delete

Tags: jquery

I am struggling on this code, since I want to create a simple shopping cart using jQuery. What I am trying to do is have an img and a span that says "add" and when the user clicks on the span stores the item on a variable, and if the user wants to delete it create a span on the shopping cart that deletes what the user selected. I have the following code.

HTML

```
<div id="gallery">
   <figure>
    <img src="img.png">
    <span class="add">Add to cart</span>
   </figure>
</div>

<div><ul id="cart"></ul></div>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var total = 1; //variable to count items 

//make span clickable and adding to shopping cart.
$(".add").on("click", function (evt) {
    var id = $(this).attr("id");

    $("<span/>", {
        html: $(this).attr("id") + ".add" + "<span class='del' id=" + id + " + data-total=" + total+++" + >Remove </span>"
            "data-total": $(this).data(".add")
    }).appendTo("cart");

});


//Delete items from shopping cart
    $("#cart").on("click", ".cancel", function (evt) {
        $(this).parent("span").remove();
        total = total - $(this).parent("span").data(".add");
        $(".items").text(total + "$");
    });


}); //End main function
```

I would appreciate all the help that I can get.
Thanks

Comment: What's happening and what you are stuck at?

Comment: It does not storage the item on the variable and does not add it to the shooping cart

Comment: @xTuckii I am able to append on the Add to Cart ...Click..check my answers

Comment: I need a little help on the .add class html...could you tell me more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have an error in this part of your code

```
$("<span/>", {
        html: $(this).attr("id") + ".add" + "<span class='del' id=" + id + " + data-total=" + total+++" + >Remove </span>"
            "data-total": $(this).data(".add")
    }).appendTo("cart");
```

selector would always be

> $("span").html( // something )

which you can later append to

> $("#cart").append( // the html) ..

let me show you a working example

```js
 var total = 1; //variable to count items 

//make span clickable and adding to shopping cart.

    $(".add").on("click", function (evt) {
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        var TotalCount =total++ ;
        var htmlToAppend =  "<span class='del' id=" + id + " + data-total=" + TotalCount +" + >  Item No ."+TotalCount +" -- Remove </span> ";
        $("#cart").append(htmlToAppend);
    
    }); 

$("#cart").on("click", ".del", function (evt) {      
        total =  $(this).closest("ul").find("span").length ;
  console.log(total);
        $(".items").text(total + "$");
  $(this).remove();         
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="gallery">
   <figure>
    <img src="img.png">
    <span class="add">Add to cart</span>
   </figure>
</div>

<div><ul id="cart"></ul></div>
```

Comment: That seems to do the trick, however, when clicking on the delete span, it does not remove the item from cart

Comment: because there isn't any onclick handler for span click...let me see what can be done to the code..to remove the span in cleanest way

Comment: yeah found the issue...the class for removing is actually .del & not .cancel..if we replace it..then the removal will work..check my updated answer

Comment: That worked perfectly!! I did not even see the .cancel    i appreciate your help! :)

Comment: is there any way to add a text that is next to the img with the .onClick function?  and display it with the remove function? @Raja

Comment: sure...you can manipulate the html... I am modifying the answer